# Webpack, environment variables passed from command line undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am setting an environment variable to pass to webpack in the following manner:

```
webpack --config client/webpack.config.js  --watch --env.local & nodemon server/server.js
```

I am able to console log `env.local` which is set to `true` as expected initially but then the file seems to be run multiple times, at which point `env` is undefined.

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  console.log(env);
  const isProd = env.production;
}
```

I have a feeling this is due to the `watch` command, but I am not sure why on consecutive runs of the function I am exporting for webpack the `env` argument is no longer being passed in.

Comment: not directly answering your question but take a look at webpack.EnvironmentPlugin https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/ and webpack-merge https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge which is a better option than trying to pass variables in argv